# Make call to GSM number using SIP

Tags: android, sip, gsm, telephony

I'm developing a application to call GSM Numbers using Sip protocol. Please anyone help me to do that ? How to Implement in Android or any open source projects available for this ?

Answer (score 1):

An android sip api is limited api , you can only call between sip account only. So if you want to develop an application to support GSM call , you can make clone of open source SIP

**1)Sip Droid**

**2) Voip**

available on github

Download From Here
https://github.com/mconf/sipdroid/archive/master.zip

Comment: Thanks a lot for replaying..  Sip Droid support GSM ? and how to setup the GSM setting in github ? need GSM gateway for that ?

Comment: I post a link for sipdroid android source code. To implement you need to have sip server that can be third party or you can have your own server.